# Get key that have been posted by a form

Tags: php, html, http-post

Is there anyway to get all the **key** from a form that I post?

My problem found when I am showing some data that get from `mysql DB`.

When I am showing 2 records, I posted 2 of the record to another **PHP** file.
But I am afraid when I was posting the record, someone is adding another record to the `DB`

My **PHP** will get 3 posted data instead of 2 (The user only post 2, because he/she is not refresh the form)

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|       Form         |         DB         |
|--------------------|--------------------|
|      2 records     |     2 records      |
|      2 records     |     3 records      | Someone Insert it
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Of course I can get `$_POST['key1']`, `$_POST['key2']`.
But my code will search for `$_POST['key1']`, `$_POST['key2']`, `$_POST['key3']`, because there are 3 records in the `DB`.

Is there a way to check what **key** only that the user `POST`?

Comment: What do you mean by the "key"? You could use hidden field to store the db ids.

Comment: for example I get the data, `$_POST['key']`, and this is not about the id, I want to get all Id that I have posted, because I use looping to show the data

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="key[]" value="1">

Comment: I don't totally understand what you are trying to do... but try using  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){echo $key; } would print key1, key2 ...

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks, just post it to become the answer, I will gladly accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//print key1, key2
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
   echo $key; 
}
```